# Wordpress Export CSV File only username and emails using wp_export

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, plugins, export-to-csv

I need some help to download the csv on wordpress with username and email only using wordpress default function wp_export().

I have tried different ways, using different agrs but unable to get only required output.

Second, It force me to download the xml only instead of csv file.

Comment: You can use plugin for export as csv data.

Comment: Function [`generate_csv`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/export-users-to-csv/trunk/export-users-to-csv.php)

Comment: Hi @brasofilo, I have used that method and plugin, but unable to download the file. Instead It force me to show all contents on screen. So I have only one choose, that is using export_wp()